# Autocomplete a specific set of possibilities in Django-admin

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I have a field in a Django model, and I want there to be a small (~20) set of possibilities (which are strings) which can be autocompleted (preferably with `django-autocomplete-light`, which I am using already) in `django-admin`. Should I make this a foreign key field and create a model containing just these 20 possibilities? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have a separate model with only those possibilities and to make the field we want to limit into a foreign key field.

Answer (score 0):

[django orm limit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) should be done something like:

```
Entry.objects.all()[:5]
```

so creating a new model for limiting number of results would not make sense.

I've looked at `django-autocomplete-light` and saw `limit_choices` [here](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/autocomplete_light/autocomplete/model.html) (didn't give it a try.

in any case it should be something like line 77 in [this snippet.](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/233/)

I hope this is helpful.